# WiFi range extender + router + bult-in data card

Tags: wifi, networking, router, wlan

Is there any hardware which can consume connection from 3G/4G SIM, LAN Ethernet cable, existing low range WiFi and can provide it as wifi access point and LAN, both.

New WiFi from this hardware should have consistent access, regardless which underlying connectivity it uses. It would be better if it is portable. 
[image: Diagram]

I am currently using SoftAP mode of WN722N wifi USB adapter. It delivers internet(via WiFi) obtained from any source(3G/4G adapter/LAN/another WiFi). It creates bridged network.

If its not possible in single device, recommend me combination of devices, with minimum cost. I expect it to serve 5 to 10 devices.

Comment: What country are you going to buy this in? If you're looking for low cost, that could make the difference.

Comment: I am from **India**.

Comment: you could try mixing up MTS usb stick with an existing router

Comment: You mean ADSL router with USB port? Closest I could find is [this](http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/home-solutions/connect/broadband-modems-and-routers/dwr-730-portable-hspa-plus-21-mbps-router)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Industrial:**

Cisco offers products with this capability: [4G Routers](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/solutions/enterprise-networks/4g-lte-solutions/index.html#~tab-selectproduct). I have used their products to build similar configurations. There are many industrial products like this from Cisco and others. They can meet all of your requirements but they are quite pricey.

**Consumer:**

[Here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MQRHQYT) is a product that is built to act as a backup to a [DSL modem](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0046TRVR6) and stand between it and your [router](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079JD7F7G). *Personally, I would recommend this setup with the three devices I linked inline and build them into an enclosure for portability.*

There are also plenty of 4G modem, router, access point combos but these will need a seperate DSL modem. [This one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07X497NZB) also has a WAN port that could be paired with a regular modem.

**DIY:**

You could pair a Raspberry Pi with a [4G module](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PSGKWT5) and then cofigure it however you like and change as needed.